# Creating pie-chart matrix from comma-separated cell data

Tags: r, csv, matrix, data-visualization, pie-chart

Given I have matrix containing data:

[image: Data]

I want to create a **pie-chart matrix**. The output should be like this[image: output]

How should I proceed in **R**?

**Note:** I want it to make pie-chart as an element of the matrix.

Comment: with caution...

Comment: One might usually start by writing some code.

Comment: Look up `par(mfrow=c(3,3))`  and `?pie`  maybe also `?text`

Comment: @RichScriven I am not able to think on how to proceed with this problem. I just need an idea..

Comment: @G5W: Yes this can be one possibility but I want it to make pie-chart as an element of the matrix

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way of doing it:

```
library(stringr)   # to split strings
library(tidyverse) # to unnest lists of numbers
library(ggplot2)   # for graphs
library(dplyr)     # for pretty code

# Define your matrix
mat <- matrix(c(NA, "1,2,3", "6,7,1", "1,2,3", NA, "8,5,2", "6,7,1", "8,5,2", NA), 
              nrow=3, 
              ncol=3,
              dimnames = list(c("P1", "P2", "P3"), c("P1", "P2", "P3"))) 

mat %>%
  # Convert matrix to a data frame
  as.table() %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  # Extract/parse numbers from strings (e.g. "1,2,3")
  mutate(Freq = str_split(Freq,",")) %>%
  unnest(Freq) %>%
  mutate(Freq = as.integer(Freq)) %>%
  # Convert the values to a percentage (which adds up to 1 for each graph)
  group_by(Var1, Var2) %>%
  mutate(Freq = ifelse(is.na(Freq), NA, Freq / sum(Freq)),
         color = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  # Plot
  ggplot(aes("", Freq, fill=factor(color))) + 
  geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity") +
  coord_polar("y") +       # Make it a pie chart
  facet_wrap(~Var1+Var2) + # Break it down into 9 charts
  # Below is just aesthetics
  theme(axis.text = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        axis.title = element_blank()) +
  guides(fill = FALSE)
```

Result:

[image]